# MySQL search multiple columns, yet force one condition

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to write a query to search on multiple columns in my database, however, I need to force an ID to be matched on top of those conditions:

```
SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, fax_did.fax_did,users.enterprise_id FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_groups ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
INNER JOIN groups ON users_groups.group_id = groups.id
INNER JOIN product ON groups.id = product.groupid
INNER JOIN fax_did ON product.productid = fax_did.productid
WHERE users.enterprise_id = 2
AND users.first_name LIKE '%test%'
OR users.last_name LIKE '%test%'
OR users.email LIKE '%test%'
OR fax_did.fax_did LIKE '%239214%'
```

I need the search condition to return results that match the enterprise_id as shown here:

```
 WHERE users.enterprise_id = 2
```

However, the other search conditions may be optional:

```
AND users.first_name LIKE '%test%'
OR users.last_name LIKE '%test%'
OR users.email LIKE '%test%'
OR fax_did.fax_did LIKE '%239214%'
```

Is there a way I can achieve this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Does this give you the results you were expecting:

```
SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, fax_did.fax_did,users.enterprise_id FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_groups ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
INNER JOIN groups ON users_groups.group_id = groups.id
INNER JOIN product ON groups.id = product.groupid
INNER JOIN fax_did ON product.productid = fax_did.productid
WHERE users.enterprise_id = 2
AND (users.first_name LIKE '%test%'
OR users.last_name LIKE '%test%'
OR users.email LIKE '%test%'
OR fax_did.fax_did LIKE '%239214%')
```

?

Comment: Perfect, works exactly as needed. Thank you so much!